# How should I approach solving this floor function?

Tags: contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that for all $n \in \Bbb Z, \lfloor\sqrt {(n)}+ \sqrt {(n+1)} \rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor$.

There must be some algebraic substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** for non-negative $n$, note that
$$
(\sqrt n + \sqrt{n+1})^2 = 2n + 1 + 2\sqrt{n^2 + n}
$$
and that $n^2 \leq n^2 + n < (n+1)^2$